# Showing the full path of a DLL in a ModLoad event

Tags: windbg

When I was debugging our application with WinDbg, I saw a 7 messages like this for different assemblies:

```
* MyApp second chance resolve: Requested assembly: "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
* MyApp second chance resolve: Trying to load: "C:\MyApp\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
ModLoad: 000002a7`366b0000 000002a7`36760000   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
ModLoad: 000002a7`36760000 000002a7`36810000   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
* MyApp second chance resolve: Loaded assembly: "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
```

However, in the list of loaded modules, it appears only once, at the latter address:

```
1:003> lm m Newtonsoft*
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
000002a7`36760000 000002a7`36810000   Newtonsoft_Json_2a736760000   (deferred)
```

Using Process Monitor, I could confirm that our application is accessing both DLLs and I could figure out the full path of both DLLs. However, that required reproducing the issue, including the restart of 2 executables.

Is it possible to configure WinDbg to show the full path of the DLL being loaded during a ModLoad event? How?

Comment: Thomas, is it still an open problem for you or have you solved it already? From what I can gather this is just Windbg being lazy (other debuggers or my own one are actually correctly outputting the  path for .NET modules). I guess a Windbg script could solve that, even though it would be quite complicated (it's not possible to be notified of module loading events from a script) but with a bit of fiddling, it should be doable.

Comment: @Neitsa: I could think of putting a breakpoint in some low level methods. But that would be quite some overhead. I was hoping for a simple switch like `.fullmodulenames 1`. Seems that this doesn't exist...

Comment: Ah yeah, sadly no such thing exist :( I was thinking on the same line as you, if you `sxe ld:*` you'll see the system stops right after calling [`ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection), the third argument being the base address, from which you can `lmvaf <addr>` which outputs the full path. It's still a complex scripting for such a basic thing... That's a real bummer.

Comment: @Neitsa: did I get you right that the information is basically there, but it's just not used? If so, I could file a feature request at Microsoft and it shouldn't be too hard to implement.